# Where is this image of a girl in a black top kissing a boy from?

Tags: queen-bonjourno

Today I have found that little picture and I really want to know where it is from. I tried reverse image search but nothing useful came up.

[image]

Thank you for the help.

Comment: This looks like some random shoujo-like image. Where do you get this image from? Someone's avatar?

Comment: It was on someone's' avatar

Comment: There is a better way to find it. Its name is "Queen Bonjorno!". Just right click it and use Google image search! ;)

Comment: The OP says he tried reverse image search and didn't get any useful results. For me, the original image gives "edward and bella anime", and a bunch of unrelated results on Google. So while you do have the right answer here, it could use some more explanation about how you found it and/or about the source itself. Also, right clicking will only work in Google Chrome or Firefox (with an extension). [Our tutorial](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/793/) has more information about how to do it in other browsers.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm using Google chrome and i right clicked and then clicked "Search Google for this image" and it gave me [this](http://goo.gl/MQCneC).

Comment: You're searching for the image in Gerret's answer to the question, not the one in the question itself. While it does get the right answer, that's not particularly helpful. That one is relatively easy to identify, while [the one in the question](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hWBDG.jpg) is quite a bit less easy since it's cropped at low resolution and present on many unrelated sites.

Comment: But you can just take one of the result pictures and search it again. It worked that way too for me!

Comment: @KarloMiličević not really if one of the result images is incorrect due to the low resolution image

Comment: That must be part of real lives in Japan.

Answer (score 22):

After searching for an hour I found in a YouTube comment on the seventh page the name of it. I found out that it is not any anime or manga. It is a artwork from *Sano Toshihide* from the visual novel **Queen Bonjourno!** (Queenボンジョルの！).

If you like the picture, here is a bigger one...

[image: Bigger Image]

<sub>This is a jpg image from a vector graphic from [ZeroChan](http://www.zerochan.net/1005696). If you want the same image you posted use this from [ZeroChan](http://www.zerochan.net/86315).</sub>

> Juliet, a princess, was in love with the main character. But she took
>   over the throne, and needed to work for the people, holding back her
>   love toward him. One day, she finally crossed the line, and slept with
>   him without knowing the impending threat from the neighboring
>   countries…
>
> One thousand years later, they all meet again at a high school, as a
>   student or as a teacher or as an older sister. The main character
>   lives a peaceful life. But triggered by a meeting with a transfer
>   student, his life changes dramatically. "I've been looking for you."
>   The curtain on the battle for the main character raises...

<sub>Information from [Visual Novel Database](http://vndb.org/v1042).</sub>

The female character is called *Sakurazaka Meguru* (桜坂 めぐる) and she is one of the main characters in the visual novel.

[image: Sakurazaka Meguru]

<sub>Image from [ZeroChan](http://www.zerochan.net/256185).</sub>

The male character I could not find... Maybe you are the main character yourself? Or because they are often "uninteresting" for such type of games... If you know what I mean ;)

Comment: Wow... I was about to give up.